# Grand Total for discrete column

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to tableau and trying to show grand total for discrete columns however it shows blank. Is there a workaround. Can one total for discrete columns?

Here's the snapshot:

[image]

I tried to follow tableaus notes and removed the discrete columns and double clicked it , however it becomes continuos and tries to aggregate it. Is there a work around?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't grand total a discrete column. It either has to be continuous OR you create a WINDOW_SUM calculation to calculate the grand total, then put the total in the Title area instead of within the table.

An easy way is to move your discrete measure from the Rows shelf to the Text shelf and then make it continuous. If you have multiple measures, you can get a similar effect with the placeholder fields Measure Names and Measure Values